# discord bot на пайтоне

Tags: python, discord

Я хочу сделать команду, пример:

/set

Бот: введите сообщение

Я: ввожу сообщение: hello

Бот отправляет: hello

Как это сделать?? У меня нету никаких догадок. Вот что я пытался сделать:

```
...
@bot.slash_command(name='set', description='...')
async def settings(ctx):
    await ctx.send('введите сообщение')
    answer = 'Я не знаю'
    await ctx.send(answer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command()
async def set(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Попробуй это

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, ответ на вопрос должен быть **исчерпывающим**. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1505518/edit)».

Comment: Мне надо именно на слеш-командах, но все равно спасибо >.<